# Eliminar archivos del repositorio en Git

Tags: git

tengo una duda. Si tengo un historial de cambios en un repositorio en git y luego decido eliminar un archivo del repositorio con un git rm --cached y a continuacion hago un nuevo commit, entonces, ¿este archivo que elimine de git  va a afectar tambien a los viejos cambios que contienen este archivo? ¿o el archivo solo queda eliminado para los cambios futuros a eliminarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces un `git rm --cached [archivo]` estas excluyendo a 'archivo' para que sus cambios no se tengan en cuenta en el proximo commit, es decir si antes has agregado a 'archivo' a la zona de 'staging' con `git add [archivo]` entonces al hacer `git rm --cached [archivo]` estas sacandolo de 'staging' para que sus cambios no se agreguen al proximo commit.
Los cambios antiguos del archivo se mantendran en commits anteriores (si existen) donde si hayas tenido en cuenta al archivo antes de hacer un commit y los cambios de tu archivo seguiran existiendo en tu disco duro pero no en el ultimo commit ya que lo excluiste.
Recuerda que la opcion `--cached` elimina del 'staging' pero no elimina tus archivos del disco duro a diferencia de `--force` que elimina de ambos.